# How can I compare results from two CSV files in Python with DictReader or Pandas? (Open to any other methods as well!)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, comparison

I am trying to compare results from two CSV files. I want it to check if the first column(ID_NUMBER) from CSV1 that matches CSV2, and then I want it to check if the values from rest of the columns match too, and give the output of "True" or "False" for the corresponding column. And At the end, I want to add a column; if all the row values are "True" it should be True, if there is one "False" it should be false
Here is the code I have:

```
import csv
import os
import sys
import difflib

def compare():

list_csv1 = []
with open('query1_results.csv' , 'rb') as query_results1:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(query_results1)
    for row1 in reader1:
        list_csv1.append(row1)

list_csv2= []   
with open('query2_results.csv' , 'rb') as query_results2:
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(query_results2)
    for row2 in reader2:
        list_csv2.append(row2)
```

CSV1:

```
{'ID_NUMBER': '1J2Wh', 'CHECKING_CODE': '20', 'SECURITY_CODE': '0', 'JOB_ID': ''}
{'ID_NUMBER': '124ggfh', 'CHECKING_CODE': '100', 'SECURITY_CODE': '0', 'JOB_ID': 'O'}
```

CSV2:

```
{'ID_NUMBER': '1J2Wh', 'CHECKING_CODE': '600', 'SECURITY_CODE': '0', 'JOB_ID': ''}
{'ID_NUMBER': '124ggfh', 'CHECKING_CODE': '100', 'SECURITY_CODE': '0', 'JOB_ID': 'O'}
```

Output I need:

```
{'ID_NUMBER': '1J2Wh', 'CHECKING_CODE': FALSE, 'SECURITY_CODE': TRUE, 'JOB_ID': TRUE}
{'ID_NUMBER': '124ggfh', 'CHECKING_CODE': TRUE, 'SECURITY_CODE': TRUE, 'JOB_ID': TRUE}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
# compare all columns except first one and join result DF with the first column
cols = df1.columns
cmp = df1[['ID_NUMBER']].join(df1[cols[1:]] == df2[cols[1:]])
```

Step by step:

```
In [53]: %paste
# generating sample data frame
cols = ['ID_NUMBER', 'CHECKING_CODE', 'SECURITY_CODE', 'JOB_ID']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 4)), columns=cols)
df2 = df1.copy()

# changing some cells
df2.ix[1, 'JOB_ID'] = 100
df2.ix[2, 'SECURITY_CODE'] = 100
df2.ix[3, 'CHECKING_CODE'] = 100
## -- End pasted text --

In [54]: df1
Out[54]:
   ID_NUMBER  CHECKING_CODE  SECURITY_CODE  JOB_ID
0         58             47             62      72
1         75             21             67      99
2         49             70             92      30
3         80             85             95      78
4         64             82             21       2

In [55]: df2
Out[55]:
   ID_NUMBER  CHECKING_CODE  SECURITY_CODE  JOB_ID
0         58             47             62      72
1         75             21             67     100
2         49             70            100      30
3         80            100             95      78
4         64             82             21       2

In [56]: %paste
# comparison
cols = df1.columns
cmp = df1[['ID_NUMBER']].join(df1[cols[1:]] == df2[cols[1:]])
## -- End pasted text --

In [57]: cmp
Out[57]:
   ID_NUMBER CHECKING_CODE SECURITY_CODE JOB_ID
0         58          True          True   True
1         75          True          True  False
2         49          True         False   True
3         80         False          True   True
4         64          True          True   True
```

**Bonus answer:** ("At the end, I want to add a column; if all the row values are "True" it should be True, if there is one "False" it should be false Here is the code I have"):

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
       a      b      c
0  False   True   True
1   True  False   True
2   True   True   True
3  False  False  False
4   True  False  False

In [16]: df['truth'] = df.sum(axis=1) > 0

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
       a      b      c  truth
0  False   True   True   True
1   True  False   True   True
2   True   True   True   True
3  False  False  False  False
4   True  False  False   True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful! I have another question, how can I add another column at the end with values "True" if all the values in that row are true, and "False" if any of them is not true?? I have been getting the error "Truth Value to the series is ambiguous".

Comment: @Pythoner1234, glad to help. Here is your new column: `df['truth'] = df.sum(axis=1) > 0`

Comment: thank you! This didn't work as I expected, it gave me TRUE for everything.

Comment: I have tried this:  df[df.columns[2:]].apply(lambda row: 1 if row > 0 else 0)

Comment: @Pythoner1234, i think not all your columns are of boolean type. I would suggest you to open a new question for this. Check my `Bonus answer` - it works if all your columns are of boolean type

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. All the columns except ID_NUMBER are Boolean. Is there a way to specify which column to look for with your answer?

Comment: @Pythoner1234, `df[['col1','col2']]` or `df[cols]` where `cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'etc.']`

Comment: Thank you!! That was very helpful. For a specific case; if a cell is empty in both CSV files, the comparison cmp is producing result "FALSE", how can I ask pandas to count empty cells as well and when compare it take it as same value. For example; empty == empty. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the code doesn't really work when there are values in CSV file 1 under ID_NUMBER column that are not in the other CSV file. Is there a way to compare the only ID_NUMBER values that are exist in both files?

Comment: @Pythoner1234, could you provide datasets, where it's _not_ working? then i'll be able to debug it

Comment: Its not working because the two DataFrames do not have identical number rows, as a result, cmp doesn't work. It gives raises an exception

Comment: @Pythoner1234, could you post a corresponding input data sets?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the CSV data you have is like below or processed to be like below:

[image]

Then the following code:

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
csv2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
csv3 = pd.merge(csv1,csv2, on='ID_NUMBER', how='inner')

#csv3 will have columns like ['ID_NUMBER', 'CHECKING_CODE_x', 'SECURITY_CODE_x', 'JOB_ID_x', 'CHECKING_CODE_y', 'SECURITY_CODE_y', 'JOB_ID_y']]

csv3['CHECKING_CODE'] = csv3.CHECKING_CODE_x == csv3.CHECKING_CODE_y
csv3['SECURITY_CODE'] = csv3.SECURITY_CODE_x == csv3.SECURITY_CODE_y
csv3['JOB_ID'] = csv3.JOB_ID_x == csv3.JOB_ID_y
csv_out = csv3[['ID_NUMBER','CHECKING_CODE',''SECURITY_CODE','JOB_ID']]
```

shall get you the result in following format:

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to compare the columns(x and y) after merging without using their names?

Comment: Yes, you can by accessing them through the column indexing like this `csv3[csv3.columns[0..n]] == csv3[csv3.columns[0..n]]` however you need to know index of the columns that you are going to compare.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think I can match them with a conditional statement for example; if text in column before _x and before _y equals, compare the values of these cols?

Comment: You can do all complex things, break the requirement into atomic and go one step at a time you will understand the code better and get quick results. In the python world I'm afraid to say something not possible.